# Why was the 21st chapter in the early American publications of A Clockwork Orange omitted?

Tags: books, adaptation-comparison, dystopia, a-clockwork-orange

Most Americans were unaware of the missing last chapter; the movie even follows the American novelization. Why in America was the 21st chapter removed when it first came to the US? In Europe the chapter is in, and now the US has the 21st chapter, but why was it removed in the first place?

Comment: Another interesting difference is the Nadsat glossary; the "London" edition had 21 chapters and no glossary and the "New York" edition had 20 chapters and a glossary.

Comment: With an accepted answer that directly addresses the question, what more "attention" are you hoping for?

Comment: @giacomocasanova Stop bumping this question just to earn a badge.

Comment: @giacomocasanova - I think it's time you accept the answer.

Answer (score 32):

Short answer: It was a decision by the american publisher. The European edition always had the final chapter.

From Wikipedia:

> The book has three parts, each with seven chapters. Burgess has stated
>   that the total of 21 chapters was an intentional nod to the age of 21
>   being recognised as a milestone in human maturation. The 21st chapter
>   was omitted from the editions published in the United States prior to
>   1986. In the introduction to the updated American text (these newer editions include the missing 21st chapter), Burgess explains that when
>   he first brought the book to an American publisher, he was told that
>   U.S. audiences would never go for the final chapter, in which Alex
>   sees the error of his ways, decides he has lost all energy for and
>   thrill from violence and resolves to turn his life around (a
>   slow-ripening but classic moment of metanoia—the moment at which one's
>   protagonist realises that everything he thought he knew was wrong).
>
> At the American publisher's insistence, Burgess allowed their editors
>   to cut the redeeming final chapter from the U.S. version, so that the
>   tale would end on a darker note, with Alex succumbing to his violent,
>   reckless nature—an ending which the publisher insisted would be 'more
>   realistic' and appealing to a U.S. audience. The film adaptation,
>   directed by Stanley Kubrick, is based on the American edition of the
>   book (which Burgess considered to be "badly flawed"). Kubrick called
>   Chapter 21 "an extra chapter" and claimed that he had not read the
>   original version until he had virtually finished the screenplay, and
>   that he had never given serious consideration to using it. In
>   Kubrick's opinion, the final chapter was unconvincing and inconsistent
>   with the book.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange#Omission_of_the_final_chapter)

Comment: An interesting case of a publisher butchering a book and also being correct about doing so.

Comment: Ah, now I understand why people says the film is so dark.

Comment: @DampeS8N Being correct? I'd say that's up for debate. For example, with the 21st chapter and no glossary the book can be seen as about choice, redemption and teenage rebellion (using a language that can't be understood by outsiders). With 20 chapters and a glossary it's pretty much about violence being bad.

Comment: @StuperUser I mean correct in about how the U.S. would prefer the book.

Comment: @DampeS8N I'd say that's up for debate too.

Comment: @StuperUser - I really don't understand that comment.  **With** the last chapter, it is about violence being bad.  Without it, the story is about free will being more important than conventional morality.  The book is better without the warm and fuzzy ending.